# Paint, Repaint, and PaintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am following the tutorial on the Oracle website about the use of RescaleOp.  I am trying to do the tutorial without an applet and convert everything to swing.  The code follows.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

/*
 * How to load an Image from an external file.
 */
public class ARGB extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img;
    float[] scales = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f };
    float[] offsets = new float[4];
    RescaleOp rop;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 24));
        g2d.drawString("Java 2D is great!", 10, 80);
        g2d.drawImage(img, rop, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("hi");

    }

    public ARGB() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/strawberry.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
        scales[3] = opacity;
        rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ARGB argb = new ARGB();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("See Through Image");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.add("Center", new LoadImage());
        JSlider opacitySlider = new JSlider(0, 100);
        frame.add("South", opacitySlider);
        opacitySlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider slider = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                argb.setOpacity(slider.getValue() / 100f);
                argb.repaint();
            }
        });
        Dimension size = argb.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension sliderSize = opacitySlider.getPreferredSize();
        frame.setSize(size.width, size.height + sliderSize.height);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

When I run it, I don't see my debug statement on line 39.  I don't really get why.
Thanks!

Comment: what is your exact issue? Please explain a bit more. what is at line 39? What title of this post says?

Comment: And don't forget to call super.paintComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added the JPanel object ie.e instance of ARGB class to the frame. You have added LoadImage object. where it is?? The debug statement is in ARGB vlass. You have to add ARGB object. Then only its paint method will be called